# Angular 9: why does thee entire rxjs lib get into build bundle?

Tags: angular, build, rxjs, size, bundle

If i create an empty base project with angular 9.1.1 and build it, the whole rxjs will be present in the final bundle.

[webpack-bundle analyzer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2zkt.png)

the package.json is the base one:

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/common": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/core": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/forms": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.1",
"rxjs": "~6.5.5",
"tslib": "^1.11.1",
"zone.js": "~0.10.3"
```

},

Is it normal? rxjs size is 70kb when building with --prod flag, that doesn't seem normal.

Comment: You are building without --prod flag and tree shaking has not yet done its job.

Comment: try migrating to rxJs 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at your file names, I can see you are not building your application with production build (unless you disabled the output hash with `--output-hashing none`).

Production build in Angular is set with `--prod` flag, or set from the `angular.json` file configuration. When you build your app for production, it's also tree shaking unused 3rd library functions like rx operators.

Besides that, I highly recommend you to use `source-map-explorer` and not webpack bundle tools.

Run those 2 commands:

`ng build --prod --source-maps`

`npx source-map-explorer dist/APP_NAME/main-es2015.*.js`

Comment: the issue was with webpack bundle analyzer, it says that in my prod bundle rxjs' size is 70kb, when in reality, as shown by  source-map-explorer,it's only 24kb.
Thanks!